# Server sends "ping request" to client in a single URL using JAX-RS and RESTeasy

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I would like to create a web application that is able to "ping" the client once the client has accessed certain URL (e.g. www.example.com/ping/hello) in order to get the round trip time between server and client. And by "ping" request i mean a simple request with a timestamp from server and client sends back response with its timestamp. I was hoping for this activity to be done with a single URL if possible.

The flow is something like this:

1. Client goes to the URL
2. Server sends the response to the client with its timestamp
3. Client then sends another response to server with new timestamp
4. Server finally concludes the connection with 200 OK

So far I've only been able to do the first and second steps but not sure how to ensure client to go to the same URL again without back to the first step.

My server code is something like this:

```java
@GET
@Path("/helloping")
public Response getPingServerClient(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
    String result = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());

    return Response.status(200).entity(result).build(); 

    //the code to receive the response from client containing timestamp
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Just to make it clear, for this way of connecting client and server, Client makes requests and Server returns resposes (Client doesn't send response). If you want two way communications you need websockets for example. Second: if the client sends the timestamp in the first request, why do you need the client to send another timestamp as a second request to close the cycle?

Comment: @Juan I think websocket could be useful for my case but I am not proficient with it as there is option for ping pong message as well but not sure where and how to start

Comment: You can Ping-pong but the Ping will be sent allways by the client. There are ways to simularé two way communication using long-polling but before doing that I would directly look into websockets.

Comment: @Juan I agree but unfortunately I am not familiar with websocket so it could take sometime to understand the websocket and implement it for my case

Comment: Your assumption here is that the System.currentTimeMillis() is guaranteed to be synchronized on two separate machines. Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think there is any such guarantee. So the results will not be accurate. Here's [a discussion](https://coderanch.com/t/380822/java/System-currentTimeMillis-universal).

Comment: What's your use case? If you don't mind, I would be interested in understanding the rationale behind what you are trying to do.

Comment: One more question... Is the server supposed to do anything with the timestamp sent by the client on the second call?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha you are correct in this case and I'm only mentioning the current time millisecond just as the idea of how to calculate the RTT in the end by finding the different with the time the packet arrived

Comment: @entpnerd I would like to experiment about IP based geolocation method, which one of the methods look quite simple [here](https://www.cs.bu.edu/faculty/crovella/paper-archive/imc04-geolocation-short.pdf). This needs for the server to ping the client to get the RTT instead of normal case of client ping the server. As for the timestamp sent by client it is only an example of some info sent in the packet

Comment: you can make a JS client. then on the server you can check if time=null [first request] and can return the timestamp of server. if time<>null this is the response from the client and you can then store or do whatever with the time. but as mentioned if they are not synced that data may not be too useful

Comment: simply include the timestamp in client request and compute the delta time on server, no ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two client to server calls. You'll have to figure out a way to differentiate between these two calls.

I can think of 3 options for this purpose:

1. HTTP header
2. Query parameter in GET request
3. POST request with a marker to differentiate the two calls

The request/response flow will be something like this:

```
Client -> Server : Request
Server -> Client : Response with timestamp t1 
Client -> Server : Request with timestamp t2 and the above mentioned marker
Server -> Client : Response 200
```

In this approach, you'll have to write custom code at both server and client side to handle the mentioned logic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of what you are proposing because you're basically forcing the client to setup up code to effectively become a server, itself. This is inconvenient for the client.

Instead, consider a ping-pong approach where the client first calls the server's `ping` endpoint, which returns the server's timestamp. As soon as the client obtains the server's `ping` response, the client is instructed to call a second `pong` method, which accepts the new timestamp.

It's easier and simpler to require the client to call web service methods than it is to force to client to become a pseudo server. Hence the recommendation.